# Is this a design flaw?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Consider two classes

```
class A{
     public:
       A(){
       }
       ~A(){
       }
};


class AImpl : public A{
      public:
         AImpl(){
             a = new AInternal();
         }
         AImpl(AInternal *a){
             this->_a = a;
         }
         ~AImpl(){
             if(a){
                delete a;
                a = null;
             }
         }
       private:
             AInternal *a;
};
```

I am trying to hide the **AInternal's** implementation and expose only **A's** interface. Two things I see here

1. class A is totally empty.
2. Hiding is achieved basically through inheritance. I have to actually use downcasting and upcasting from A to AImpl and vice versa.

Is this a good design. Being very inexperienced in designing, I cannot see the pitfalls of it and why it is bad?

Comment: May-be something that compiles? So the user only sees A, which does absolutely nothing? What good does the inheritance do? - Google for "pimpl" (pointer to implementation).

Comment: Note that the `if(a)` check in the destructor is unnecessary: first, you're allowed to delete null pointers, and second, `a` will never be null when the destructor is called (`new` throws an exception on failure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to hide the AInternal's implementation and expose only A's interface.

I think you are trying to do something like [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Here is an example:

```
 class IA {                                               
 public:
         IA() {}
         virtual ~IA() {}
         virtual void dosth() =0;
 };

 class Factory {
 private:
         class A : public IA {
         public:
                 A () {}
                 virtual ~A() {}

                 void dosth() { cout << "Hello World"; }
         };

 public:
         Factory () {}
         virtual ~Factory() {}

         IA*newA() { return new A; }
 };
```

And the usage of Factory class:

```
Factory f;
IA*a = f.newA();
a->dosth();
return 0;
```

Comment: I disagree. It's not really a factory, it's more of a wrapper.

Comment: I think qba's point is that a factory can hide the concrete class by just returning an abstract base class pointer. That's sort of what the question is asking.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought about.

Answer (score 18):

You're overcomplicating things by using 3 classes. I think what you're looking for is the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm).

Comment: +1. And you probably want to use a smart pointer for your pImpl member to enhance exception safety.  I think boost::scoped_ptr is probably ideal.

Answer (score 0):

IMO AInternal makes no sense. Whatever you do there, should be done in AImpl. Otherwise, it's ok to do that in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The code is rather obtuse, so I would be concerned with maintaining it six months down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do it this way, then the destructor `~A` needs to be `virtual`.

Comment: Destructors in cpp always should be virtual, not only in such constructions.

Comment: @qba: there are three major good options for difference uses: virtual public destructor; non-virtual protected destructor; or documenting the class as not for use as a base class with dynamic polymorphism. Very occasionally, for particular tricks: private destructor+friends. The ship has probably sailed on the third option in this example. IMO, though, "you have to make all your destructors virtual, because I reserve the right to use your class for dynamic polymorphism even though it's not designed for that", isn't a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be combining two common design features:

1) AInternal is a "pimpl". It provides for better encapsulation, for example if you need to add a new field to AInternal, then the size of AImpl doesn't change. That's fine.

2) A is an base class used to indicate an interface. Since you talk about upcasting and downcasting, I assume you want dynamic polymorphism, meaning that you'll have functions which pass around pointers or references to A, and at runtime the referands will actually be of type AImpl. That's also fine, except that A's destructor should either be virtual and public, or non-virtual and protected.

I see no other design problems with this code. Of course you'll need to actually define the interface A, by adding some pure virtual member functions to it that you implemented in AImpl. Assuming you plan to do that, there's nothing wrong with using an empty base class for the purpose which in Java is served by interfaces (if you know Java). Generally you'd have some kind of factory which creates AImpl objects, and returns them by pointer or reference to A (hence, upcasts them). If the client code is going to create AImpl objects directly then that might also be fine, and in fact you might not need *dynamic* polymorphism at all. You could instead get into templates.

What I don't see is why you would ever have to downcast (that is, cast an A* to AImpl*). That's usually bad news. So there may be some problems in your design which can only be revealed by showing us more of the definitions of the classes, and the client code which actually uses A and AImpl.